# Server to server Socket IO messaging

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

**Context:**

1. Node.js running a server with `require("socket.io");`
2. Node.js running another server with `require("socket.io-client");`
3. Receiving acknowledgements (from the other server) when using the standard :

`io.on("connection", function() { console.log("Something connected."); });`

**Problem:**

Unfortunately, I cannot get the CLIENT on either server **both are running client & server socket.io** to emit a message to the server of the other.

I realize it's probably a code error, so I'll include that for correctness' sake, but for the record I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong semantically as opposed to code-wise.

**Code: (LoginServer.js)**

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var ioc = require("socket.io-client");

var LoginServer = (function() {
    function LoginServer() {
        this.gameServerSocket = ioc.connect("http://localhost:3031", {reconnect: true});
    }

    LoginServer.prototype.initialize = function() {
        var self = this;

        io.listen(3032);
        io.on("connection", function(socket) {
            socket.emit("connection");
        });

        this.gameServerSocket.on("connection", function() {
            console.log("Game Server Connected!");
            self.gameServerSocket.emit("login", {accountName: "default"});
        });
    }

    return LoginServer;
})();

exports.LoginServer = LoginServer;
```

**Code: (GameServer.js)**

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var ioc = require("socket.io-client");

var GameServer = (function() {
    function GameServer() {
        this.loginServerSocket = ioc.connect("http://localhost:3032", {reconnect: true});
        this.loginServerSocket.emit("connection");
    }

    GameServer.prototype.initialize = function() {
        var self = this;

        io.listen(3031);
        io.on("connection", function(socket) {
            socket.emit("connection");
        });

        this.LoginServerResponses();
    }

    GameServer.prototype.LoginServerResponses = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.loginServerSocket.on("connection", function() {
            console.log("Login Server Connected!");
        });
        this.loginServerSocket.on("login", function(data) {
            console.log("Login Server:", data);
        });
    }

    return GameServer;
})();

exports.GameServer = GameServer;
```

Comment: Are the two modules meant to be running in different machines?

Comment: Also, why have each of them fullfill both server and client roles looks like overkill. You may want to have login server to be a socket server, and game server to be client. This doesn't prevent bi-directional communication between them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MehdiElFadil , they will indeed eventually be used on different machines at which point I will switch out `localhost` for the correct public IP address. For the time being, both are on my local machine. To address your second question, there exists a third server for the database which the client needs to be able to send and receive from but I'm unsure whether your response applies in that situation as well.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the piece of code that calls the game and login server modules? Would like to see how these are instantiated and initialized...

Comment: confirmed, its a code-wise problem, it is 100% possible to make them connected, I'll see if I can make an answer in a lil bit

Comment: @JoeTannoury I'd appreciate that. @MehdiElFadil the only other code is calling `var gs = new GameServer()` and subsequently, `gs.initialize()` (likewise with LoginServer)

Comment: @AndrueAnderson Your code is working fine. Check my answer for details. I also included a possible improvement by reducing the number of sockets you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more testing, I realized **your code is working fine.** Maybe you're calling your modules incorrectly? I used this as my index.js and the two server-client pairs connected fine:

```
// index.js
var GameServer = require('./GameServer.js').GameServer;
var LoginServer = require('./LoginServer.js').LoginServer;

var lserver = new LoginServer();
var gserver = new GameServer();

lserver.initialize();
gserver.initialize();
```

---

## Side note on sockets

I believe you can accomplish what you want to do with only 1 stream between the login and game servers. Here a redo of your code using only 1 server and 1 client that does the same thing:

GameServer.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');

function GameServer() { }

GameServer.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.httpServer = http.createServer();
    self.ioServer = io(self.httpServer);

    self.ioServer.listen(3031);
    self.ioServer.on("connection", function(socket) {
        socket.emit("connection");
    });

    this.LoginServerResponses();
}

GameServer.prototype.LoginServerResponses = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.ioServer.on("connection", function() {
        console.log("Login Server Connected!");
    });
    this.ioServer.on("login", function(data) {
        console.log("Login Server:", data);
    });
}

exports.GameServer = GameServer;
```

LoginServer.js:

```
var ioc = require("socket.io-client");

function LoginServer() {
    this.gameServerSocket = ioc.connect("http://localhost:3031", {reconnect: true});
}

LoginServer.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.gameServerSocket.on("connection", function() {
        self.gameServerSocket.emit("connection");
    });

    this.gameServerSocket.on("connection", function() {
        console.log("Game Server Connected!");
        self.gameServerSocket.emit("login", {accountName: "default"});
    });
}

return LoginServer;

exports.LoginServer = LoginServer;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jon, I've mentioned this a couple times in various comments but I actually have another server hosting the database which also uses socket.io-client to connect. I'd rather not have them all connect through the same port, socket etc, and I'd rather not have to emit tens or hundreds of minimally different events (for example, not all servers that connect are going to be the login server)

Comment: @AndrueAnderson If you have a reason for two sockets then so be it. :) Though, I would like to point out that if my main answer to your question solves the problem you asked, I would like my answer to be selected. As I said in this answer, your code is working fine. You may just be requiring the two modules incorrectly.

Comment: The "answer" you provided, unfortunately, was not an answer at all as it was implied by my post that I had already had this method working. **See point "3."**

Comment: To solve my problem you would have had to address it, which was clearly outlined: **I cannot get the CLIENT on either server -both are running client & server socket.io- to emit a message to the server of the other. (implied 'via the socket.io-client library')**

Comment: @AndrueAnderson Did you test my solution? Using the addition code I give in the first part of the answer, I got the two modules to emit the "connection" message to each other successfully.

Comment: Again, I already had this solution working. I mentioned this in the original post. There is no need to test your solution, it was already implemented, already working. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson Ah, I missed the keyword "client". Are you wondering why the "login" message is never received by the GameServer module?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why each client can't connect to the opposing server

Comment: @AndrueAnderson They are connecting just fine, as already stated. The problem is that you are listening for messages on the wrong server-client pair, while the other pair is the one generating the messages. This would be solved if you had only used ONE client and ONE server, but for reasons unexplained to us, you don't want to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Unfortunately, I cannot get the CLIENT on either server both are running client & server socket.io to emit a message to the server of the other."

What you really want to do is 1 server, and allow clients to connect.

The server can communicate to the clients, so does the clients to the server, back and forth.

**server.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.listen(3032);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user(a client) connected!');

    // lets welcome this particular client with a nice msg :)
    socket.emit('msg group', 'Welcome client! you can emit msgs for me to tell every client in "to everyone please"');

    // lets tell everyone someone joined
    io.emit('msg group', 'guys someone special joined :)!');

    socket.on('to everyone please', function(freedomMsg) {
        io.emit('msg group', "a client told me (the server) to send this to everyone (every clients)!: " + freedomMsg);
    });
});
```

**aClient.js**

```
var ioc = require("socket.io-client");
var socket = ioc("http://localhost:3032");
// general chat
socket.on('msg group', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
function msgEveryone(message) {
    socket.emit('to everyone please', message);
}

msgEveryone('whats up guys?');
```

I hope that with this you'll understand a bit more on how socket.io (or sockets in general) works :)

Comment: I find your 'answer' to be extremely patronizing. Not only did you not comprehend my question, you also embarrassed yourself by providing what you assumed to be a solution. You've further embarrassed yourself by implying that you have a greater understanding of socket.io "(or sockets in general)" than I. No, I did not want 1 server for clients to connect to. I have multiple servers that need to connect to each other and both send and receive messages. The `socket.io-client` is supposed to allow this, acting like the automatically served client in a normal setup.

Comment: The problem is that, in my code, the sockets instantiated through the `socket.io-client` library are not able to emit messages to the server(s) they connect to. 
I'm using multiple servers for multiple functionalities, one game server (depicted), one login server, and one database server.

Comment: I don't see the point in having to use multiple servers here, any server and client can communicate back and forth with no problem

Comment: Security, obviously. Why would I allow a client to connect to the database?

Comment: Isn't it the same level of security

Comment: If the computer running the Database Server allows only a single connection by a **pre-defined IP address** (the game server, or the login server) then it is much more secure than allowing each client to connect to the database for the equivalent functionality. In other words, **no, it isn't the same**

Answer (score 0):

#### Code: (GameServer.js)

first delete these code :

```
this.loginServerSocket.on("login", function(data) {
    console.log("Login Server:", data);
});
```

second change code:

```
GameServer.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var self = this;

    io.listen(3031);
    io.on("connection", function(socket) {
        socket.emit("connection");
    });

    this.LoginServerResponses();
}
```

to

```
GameServer.prototype.initialize = function () {
    var self = this;

    io.listen(3031);
    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
        socket.emit("connection");
        socket.on("login", function (data) {
            console.log("Login Server:", data);
        });
    });

    this.LoginServerResponses();
}
```

Comment: With that I can't implicitly differentiate between connections.. I have multiple servers connecting, using 'socket.on' would send a "login" message to any server that connected rather than to the Login Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**LoginServer.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var ioc = require("socket.io-client");

var LoginServer = (function() {
function LoginServer() {
    this.gameServerSocket = ioc.connect("http://localhost:3031", {reconnect: true});
}

LoginServer.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var self = this;

    io.listen(3032);
    io.on("connection", function(socket) {
        // a client, maybe game server, is connected
        socket.on("login", function(data){ console.log("Credentials: "+ data); });
    });

    this.gameServerSocket.on("connect", function() {
        console.log("Connected to Game Server!");
        // Send event to game server
    });
}

    return LoginServer;
})();

exports.LoginServer = LoginServer;
```

**GameServer.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var ioc = require("socket.io-client");

var GameServer = (function() {
function GameServer() {
    this.loginServerSocket = ioc.connect("http://localhost:3032", {reconnect: true});
}

GameServer.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var self = this;

    io.listen(3031);
    io.on("connection", function(socket) {
        // a client, maybe login server, is connected
    });

    this.LoginServerResponses();
}

GameServer.prototype.LoginServerResponses = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.loginServerSocket.on("connect", function() {
        console.log("Connected to Login Server !");
        // Try to login
        self.loginServerSocket.emit("login", {accountName: "default"});
    });
}

return GameServer;
})();

exports.GameServer = GameServer;
```